# Not sure where there is an unitialized value created by heap allocation

Tags: c, memory, malloc

Everything seems to be working fine, memory is allocating and freeing and doing what its supposed to be doing but when I check it with valgrind --track-origins=yes I get this conditional jump after entering in a name and a number.

```
==25590== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25590==    at 0x4007BD: add_car (in /students/5/gmi6y5/cs2050/lab4/a.out)
==25590==    by 0x400704: main (in /students/5/gmi6y5/cs2050/lab4/a.out)
==25590==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==25590==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==25590==    by 0x4006D9: main (in /students/5/gmi6y5/cs2050/lab4/a.out)

typedef struct FreightCars_
{
    char *name;
    int number;
    struct FreightCars_ *next_car;
}FreightCar;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
            printf("Insufficient number of arguements\n");
            return 0;
    }

    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    FreightCar *engine = (FreightCar*)malloc(sizeof(FreightCar));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
            printf("Enter in freight car name and number: ");
            add_car(engine);
    }
    free_cars(engine);

 return 0;
}

void add_car(FreightCar *engine)
{
    FreightCar *newPtr = (FreightCar*)malloc(sizeof(FreightCar));
    newPtr->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STR_LEN);

    if(newPtr == NULL)   
    {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    scanf("%s", newPtr->name);
    scanf("%d", &newPtr->number);
    newPtr->next_car = NULL;

    if(engine->next_car == NULL)
    {
            engine->next_car = newPtr;
            printf("added at the beginning\n");     
    }
    else
    {
            FreightCar *currentPtr = engine;
            while(currentPtr->next_car != NULL)
            {
                    currentPtr = currentPtr->next_car;
            }
            currentPtr->next_car = newPtr;
            printf("added later\n");
    }
    free(newPtr->name);
}

void free_cars(FreightCar *engine)
{
    if(engine == NULL)
    {
            printf("Linked list is empty now\n");
    }
    else
    {
            free_cars(engine->next_car);
    }
    free(engine);
    engine = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You allocate memory, assign it to `engine`, but you don't initialise its contents anywhere.

Comment: I changed it to this and I still get same thing.
`FreightCar *engine = NULL;
 engine = (FreightCar*)malloc(sizeof(FreightCar));`

Comment: Side note: the recursion depth of the `free_cars` function is equal to the length of the list. You can write that function with no recursion simply by storing the `next_car` pointer in a temporary variable, and then freeing the current item.

Comment: If you compile your program with the `-ggdb` flag, `valgrind` will be able to point out the individual lines on which events are taking place, rather than just the function name. Highly recommended.

Comment: consider using `FreightCar *engine = malloc( sizeof *engine );` . Less code-duplication and [less likely to hide an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Also there is a potential buffer overflow with `scanf("%s", newPtr->name);`. This is just as bad as using `gets`.  You need to specify a length parameter with `scanf`, or use a different function such as `fgets`. Also perhaps allocate `MAX_STR_LEN+1` bytes, to allow for the null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

In main you do

```
FreightCar *engine = (FreightCar*)malloc(sizeof(FreightCar));
```

then in a for loop you call

```
        add_car(engine);
```

add_car does

```
if(engine->next_car == NULL)
```

But as @Oli Charlesworth pointed out in a comment, you have not initialised the memory pointed to by engine, so you are making a decision based on unitialised memory contents here, hence the Valgrind complaint.